# How to prove that that we can not have X(j)+ and X(j) - simultaneously positive in an LP?

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

As we all know, in a linear programming problem, any variable x(j) car be replaced with the difference between 2 non negative vars.

X(j) = X(j)+  -   X(j)-

How do we know that in a base solution, we can never have X(j)+ and X(j)- simultaneously strictly positive?

Do I need to suppose a problem and work on it by splitting each variables into x+  - x- ? But that won't prove to me anything in the end..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: textbooks typically say the Simplex method can only handle non-negative variables. That is wrong: LP solvers can handle free variables directly. We still can use variable splitting in some interesting modeling cases even if we can use free variables.

If the objective minimizes `|X|` (i.e. it minimizes `Xplus + Xmin`) we know not both  `Xplus` and `Xmin` can be nonzero.

There is also an other, more exotic argument. If the LP matrix columns `Xplus` and `Xmin` are the same except for the sign, they can not appear both in the basis (if they would, the basis matrix `B` would be singular). This argument is of course related to the Simplex method.

But there are cases where both `Xplus` and `Xmin` can be nonzero. This is sometimes called `non-convexity`. In that case one would need to add a binary variable `B` with:

```
Xplus <= M*B
Xmin <= M*(1-B)
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I feel that I don't really get it. Could you please modify your answer with more details and examples ?
Just in a simplier way please if you could :)

Comment: My point is, in general you cannot prove your claim, because it is not true. There are special cases where it is true.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it does not matter: since you are interested in the value of x, both (5, 5) and (0, 0) for example are valid representation of the same solution x=0.

Why do you need one of the values to be 0?

Comment: I have never seen a model where it did not matter.